# Received: (from www-data@localhost)

Tags: php, sendmail

All mails coming from my server has `Received: (from www-data@localhost)` even though I've set `127.0.0.1 mydomain.org mydomain server2` in /etc/hosts. I think that's the reason why it's ending up in the spam folder.

How can I change this `Received: (from www-data@localhost)`?

```
    $headers = "Sender: " . $fromMail . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $fromMail . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $replayFromMail . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    mail($urow['email'],$subject,$notify,$headers);
```

I also tried adding -f no-replay@mydomain.org:

```
mail($urow['email'],$subject,$notify,$headers,"-f no-replay@mydomain.org");
```

Why I think it's related to spam problem?

from http://cbl.abuseat.org/

> This IP address is HELO'ing as "localhost.localdomain" which violates
>   the relevant standards (specifically: RFC5321).
>
> The CBL does not list for RFC violations per-se. This *particular*
>   behaviour, however, correlates strongly to spambot infections. In
>   other words, out of thousands upon thousands of IP addresses HELO'ing
>   this way, all but a handful are infected and spewing junk. Even if it
>   isn't an infection, it's a misconfiguration that should be fixed,
>   because many spam filtering mechanisms operate with the same rules,
>   and it's best to fix it regardless of whether the CBL notices it or
>   not.

Comment: Did you re-configure the mail client after changing your `/etc/hosts` file? What does the output of `hostname` give?

Comment: Yes I did. it gives me server2 and `hostname -f` gives me my domain

Comment: And sendmail is your mail-sending daemon? I can help with exim, but I haven't used sendmail. Hopefully someone else can give some insight

Comment: [Here is how you ask this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/570369/).  Notice that the questioner names the MTS in use and provides details of how that MTS is configured.

Comment: Have you restarted/HUPed sendmail daemon after changing `/etc/hosts`?  AFAIR sendmail sets "this host email name" during daemon startup.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip yes I did...

Comment: Try adding -a 'From:no-reply' as an argument to mail